# asp vnext, ignore route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core

i am using vnext and am using routes, but it routes EVERYTHING.

this is fine (from Startup.cs):

```
application.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // setup routes
                // default mapping
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });
```

but then when i use (in views)

```
<link href='@Url.Content("~/CDN/r.css")' rel="stylesheet" />
```

or

```
<img src="/CDN/i.png" />
```

it gives a 404 error on those.

so how to set up ignore routes as in the previous versions?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register a `StaticFiles` middleware before MVC for your case where you want to serve static files like `.css`, `.png` etc. So the request for static files would be served by this middleware and would not reach MVC.

```
// Add static files to the request pipeline.
app.UseStaticFiles();

application.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                // setup routes
                // default mapping
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });
```

You would need to add the package `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` in project.json to get it.

Comment: still the same. 404. !? i've add the nuget, i've added the usestaticfiles and the css and png files are still resulting with 404.

Comment: Did you place your `CDN` folder under the `wwwroot` folder? Static files should go under the `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: yep. that was it. thnx A LOT for sticking with me and helping me <3 been absent a bit, but just tried that now and it does indeed fix things. will edit the answer and accept.